# regex issue with swift

Tags: regex, swift

I don't really know much about regex, I'm trying to create a pattern which will match the following numbers:

- 0610000000
- 0620000000
- 0600000000
- 0710000000
- 0720000000
- 0730000000
- 0740000000
- 0760000000
- 0780000000
- 0790000000
- 0810000000
- 0820000000
- 0830000000
- 0840000000

so basically the first digit has to always be 0, the second digit will always be between 6 to 8, and from the third digit any number

Comment: What did you try? Length limitation?

Comment: You can use a site such as [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and try to come up with the pattern you are after. What you are after is relatively simple and thus can be used for learning.

Comment: thanks for the site. @Thomas, I tried phoneNumber.substringToIndex(<#index: String.Index#>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your solution:

```
^0[6-8]\d{8}$
```

explanation:

```
^0[6-8]\d{8}$

    ^ assert position at start of a line
    0 matches the character 0 literally
    [6-8] match a single character present in the list below
        6-8 a single character in the range between 6 and 8
    \d{8} match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: {8} Exactly 8 times
    $ assert position at end of a line
```

Comment: thanks but from that website regx101, what does this mean No match groups were extracted.

This means that your pattern matches but there were no (capturing (groups)) in it that matched anything in the subject string.

Comment: @congolesedevelopper: You can use regular expressions to *extract* information. This is done through what are called *capturing groups*. In your case, I am assuming that you just want to match a given pattern to see if it fits what you are after, thus capturing groups are not needed.